# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint. (MeasureUnit class)

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I know this topic has been dealt with lots, but I can't find anything similar to my problem.

I have 3 classes:

```
public class MeasureUnit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DataSource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ExperienceMetric
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ...
    public int DataSourceId { get; set; }
    public int MeasureUnitId { get; set; }
    public int ExperiencePillarId { get; set; }
    public virtual DataSource DataSource { get; set; }
    public virtual MeasureUnit MeasureUnit { get; set; }
    public virtual ExperiencePillar ExperiencePillar { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, DataSource and MeasureUnit are identical and as basic as you can get.

My problem is as follows. When I try seed my database in the console with update-database, I get the foreign key error for MeasureUnit. If I delete the reference to MeasureUnit from the ExperienceMetric class (navigation and Id), everything runs fine.

I'm not understanding why the seed would work for one class, but not for a second identical class?

Comment: Please show your seed code

Answer (score 0):

My problem was actually just in the way I was seeding my database. I was creating an ExperienceMetric and then trying to create the children to this entity without first saving changes. As a result, the database was not able to create an Id for the experience metric to assign to its children and thus the conflict.